# AsyncTaskLoader not loading JSON data to RecyclerView when returning from another fragment

Tags: android, json, fragment, android-recyclerview, asynctaskloader

I'm adding new JSON item by POST from AddItem fragment and when item is added you return to ItemListFragment where I call `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, mLoaderCallbacks);` at `onStart()`. But the newly added item doesn't show on RecyclerView. If I refresh RecyclerView with SwipeRefreshLayout then the new item shows.

BaseFragmentActivity:

```
public class BaseFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment newFragment = new AddItem();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = new ItemListFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

AddItem:

```
    addItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        addItem();

                        Fragment newFragment = new ItemListFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                        transaction.commit();
                    }

  public void addItem(){
        String item = itemEditText.getText().toString();
        String category = categoryEditText.getText().toString();

        Item itemModel = new Item(item, category, false);
        ItemPoster.post(itemModel);
    }
```

ItemListFragment:

```
@Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, mLoaderCallbacks);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force your adapter to render new item calling [RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) or [RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted%28int%29).

Comment: At onBindViewHolder() I could do something like if(position == getItemCount() -1) notifyDataSetChanged(); But that isn't working, and anyway shouldn't the recyclerview get updated after transaction because it should be loading recyclerview again?

Comment: @neX, you mustn't call notifyDataSetChanged from onBindViewHolder (it's useless and may become a cycle).
I think, you should call notifyDataSetChanged after addItem, but I don't know what is ItemPoster.

Comment: ItemPoster is just posting item to server. I'm not sure where I can call notfiDataSetChanged when i'm adding item on other class and then doing transaction to go to the recyclerview fragment.

Comment: @neX, it depends on your adapter. For example, if it is backed by a List, you shoud call `notify...` just after `List#add`.